# Proving that a $C^\infty$ regularizing contraction semigroup leave a subspace invariant.

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, schwartz-space, invariance, unbounded-operators

In Villani's *Hypocoercity*, I am faced with proving a statement which is indicated by the title.

> Consider a $C^\infty$ function $V: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, convergeing to $+\infty$ fast enough at infinity. For $x, v \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, set
>
> $$
> f_\infty(x,v) := \frac{e^{[V(x) + \frac{\vert v \vert^2}{2}]}}{Z}, \quad \mu(dxdv) = f_\infty(x,v)dxdv,
> $$
> where $Z$ is chosen in such a way that $\mu$ is a probability measure. Define
>
> $$
> \mathcal{H}:= L^2(\mu),\quad 
> L := -\Delta_v + v\cdot \nabla_v + v\cdot \nabla_x - \nabla V(x)\cdot \nabla_v
> $$
>
> where $L$ is an unbounded operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with its domain $D(L)\subset \mathcal{H}$.
>
> The associated equation is the kinetic Fokker-Planck equation with confinement potential $V$, in the form
> $$
> \partial_t h + Lh = 0 \cdots (*)
> $$

It is known that the above equation $(*)$ generates a $C^\infty$ regularizing contraction semigroup in $L^2(\mu)$.

Later in the book, it says since $Lh \in \mathcal{K}'$ for $h \in \mathcal{K}' \cap \mathcal{S}$, $L$ leaves $\mathcal{K}'$ invariant and **therefore so does $e^{-tL}$**. Here,  $\mathcal{K}'$ is some specific subspace of $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ is a dense topological vector space of $\mathcal{H}$, for example, the Schwartz space.

(1) I really don't understand why the invariance of $\mathcal{K}'$ under $L$  leads to that of $\mathcal{K}'$ under $e^{-tL}$.

(2) Also, I am wondering if $e^{-tL}$ leaves the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$ invariant, too.

I'd really appreciate it if you'd help me. Thanks!